# How to display data in Spinner from Json Array in Android

Tags: android

```
class roleitem extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RoleItem = HttpHitter.ExecuteData(RoleItem);
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(RoleItem);

     stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i < count; i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(RoleItem);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, stringArray);

        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
        rolespinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is my asynk task after parsing am getting RoleItem =["A","B]

and on Postexcute I want bind this data in Spinner but I am getting Error in RoleItem The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(roleeditpage.roleitem, int, ArrayList) is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, stringArray);
```

*this* in the ArrayAdapter constructor is refering to AsyncTask class and AsyncTask doesn't extend Context in any way. Replacing *this* into *getApplicationContext()* or *getActivity()* (only use getActivity() when your AsyncTask is an inner class of a fragment) should do the trick because an Activity is extending Context and ArrayAdapter first parameter is asking for a class extending Context.